# Seam 2.2.2.Final caching strategy

Tags: caching, seam, ehcache

I am using seam 2.2.2.Final/hibernate and jpa and I was wondering how to handle some performance issues I am facing. I have very complex forms that when are requested I need first to initialize some lists.

So I want to cache this lists and I was thinking that the seam manager component could actually do the work. However, if I follow this approach I will need to create 10-12 classes /manager components. One manager component for each list.

And I was wondering if there is another caching strategy I could follow based on seam framwework or hibernate

Answer (score 0):

A controller for each list isn't necessary.  You can divide it into whatever makes sense for your code organization.
Caching with ehcache are get and put operations, they can be managed in methods, not necessarily separated classes.

You could just as easily have one caching controlling class with cache management methods:

```
 public List<List1> getList1FromCache() {
      (List<List1>) this.cacheProvider.get("list1Cache", "list1");
      // refresh cache if null;
      return list1;
 }

 public List<List2> getList2FromCache() {
      (List<List1>) this.cacheProvider.get("list2Cache", "list2");
      // refresh cache if null;
      return list2;
 }
```

... etc

With each list's properties configured in the ehcache property file.